# How to crawl multiple tables in a PostgreSQL database using a single Glue Crawler?

Tags: aws-glue

I have a PostgreSQL database that contains many tables. I want to crawl a subset of those tables. Can I do this with a single Glue Crawler, or do I need one Crawler per table?

For example, let's say I want to crawl the `customer` and `address` tables, and create corresponding `customer` and `address` tables in the Glue Data Catalog. I configured a single Glue Crawler with two JDBC data sources: one for `customer` and one for `address`. However, when I run the crawler, I get the "Internal Service Exception" with no additional details. When I configure a separate Crawler for each table, it works.